# Alignment of the bar labels of ganttbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt

The labels of `\ganttbar` in [`pgfgantt`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfgantt) are right aligned by default (at the border of chart).
Is it possible to have it left aligned?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Do you really mean right? Maybe left?

Comment: yes sorry.. edited the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the question is about the label text align then you can use a coordinate intersection as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0cm]
\node[align=center] at (-4,0) (o) {This is\\ adjust node}; %Remove the text later or change it to a \coordinate
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid, bar label font=\Large,bar label text={--#1$\rightarrow$}]{12}
    \gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
    \ganttbar[name=b1,bar label anchor/.style={draw,right = of o|-b1}]{Task 1}{1}{3} \\
    \ganttbar[name=b2,bar label anchor/.style={draw,right = of o|-b2},bar label font=\color{orange}]{Task 2}{4}{10} \\
    \ganttbar[name=b3,bar label anchor/.style={draw,right = of o|-b3},bar label font=\MakeUppercase]{Final task}{11}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (b1) {}; %This line is for demo
    \draw[dashed] (o) |- (b1); % This too!
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This would give

[image]

As seen from the image we first provide an adjusting node. Since the north west point of the chart is the origin we just go left from the origin where I placed the node `(o)`. Then we take the orthogonal intersection of this point and the bar center which is shown with a black dot and the intersection is shown with a dashed line. We put the bar labels' left side at these intersections hence they become left aligned. To be able to refer to each bar label we need to provide some names as can be seen from code.

Note that, I placed `node distance=0cm` to snap to the point without extra padding otherwise the labels would be as far as this key dictates. Moreover, I put the `draw` option to the anchor style keys to see if it is working properly and simply can be removed later.

Comment: Wow, i hoped is something more compact. Thanks for the great and clear explanation!

Comment: @percusse: Done!

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation of pgfgantt](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt) provides several examples. One of them is given below. The the Task 1 is centered (default) and Task 3 is right aligned.

The relevant key is `bar label inline anchor/.style`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid, hgrid, inline]{12}
\gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
\ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{3}
\ganttbar[bar label inline anchor/.style=above]{Task 2}{5}{10} \\
\ganttbar[bar label shape anchor=left,%
bar label inline anchor/.style=right]{Task 3}{2}{7}
\ganttbar[inline=false]{Final task}{11}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another approach for left-aligning the bar labels is to use `align=left, text width=<some value>`, where `<some value>` should be large enough to accommodate the widest label. This approach has the advantage that you don't need to adjust the options for every bar; you only need to provide the keys once to the `ganttchart` environment.

[image]

(based on percusse's MWE)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[
    vgrid,
    hgrid,
    bar label font=\Large,
    bar label text={--#1$\rightarrow$},
    bar label anchor/.append style={align=left, text width=8em}
]{12}
    \gantttitle{Title}{12} \\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{3} \\
    \ganttbar[bar label font=\color{orange}]{Task 2}{4}{10} \\
    \ganttbar[bar label font=\MakeUppercase]{Final task}{11}{12}
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Comment: mmm this seems a good solution, and works very well,
thanks Jake,
 However, i tried with groups and milestones (to have a nicely formatted chart), e.g. 
`\begin{ganttchart}
[bar label anchor/.append style={align=left, text width=16em}, 
[group label anchor/.append style={align=left, text width=16em}, 
[milestone label anchor/.append style={align=left, text width=16em}, 
y unit chart=0.5cm, x unit=0.35cm,vgrid={*2{white},*1{black, dashed}}]{36} `

but without any luck! where is the error?

Comment: You have spurious `[` in your options. The syntax is `\begin{ganttchart}[ <first style>/.append style={<options>}, <second style>/.append style={<options>}, ... ]`

Comment: The code example does not left-align for me.