# Titles aligned horizontally above nodes in figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

I am trying to create a flow chart going left-right where each stage has a header aligned with it, at a certain height above the chart. I am trying to use the [Hydrogen Splitting Example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/hydrogen-splitting/) (see the underlines titles), but that example uses fixed positioning, and I would ideally like to use a fixed vertical coordinate (perhaps based relative to my tallest column), and a relative horizontal one.

The below code doesn't work, but hopefully shows what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1mm, auto,
    box/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        fill=blue!20, 
        text width=5em,
        text centered,
        rounded corners, 
        minimum height=4em
    }]  

    % First column
    \node [box]                  (b1)   {Box 1};
    \node [box, below=of b1]     (b2)   {Box 2};
    \node [box, below=of b2]     (b3)   {Box 3};

    % Second column
    \node [box, right=of b2, xshift=30mm]   (b4) {Box 4};

    % Labels at top
    \node [above=of b1, font=\large] (title1) {\underline{Column One}};
    \node [right=of title1, above=of b4, font=\large]{\underline{Column Two}};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have used a similar idea to have labels at left side of the diagram. So same can be utilized to have orthogonal intersections of some coordinate and the column placement. You can see [this answer for a longer explanation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52107/alignment-of-the-bar-labels-of-ganttbar/52112#52112).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option would be to use the implicit syntax `( <p> |- <q> )` (or `( <q> -| <p> )`) to get `(u,v)`, where `u` is the x-coordinate of `<p>` and v is the y-coordinate of `<q>`; in your case, you could use `at (title1-|b4)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1mm and 30mm, auto,
    box/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        fill=blue!20, 
        text width=5em,
        text centered,
        rounded corners, 
        minimum height=4em
    }]  

    % First column
    \node [box]                  (b1)   {Box 1};
    \node [box, below=of b1]     (b2)   {Box 2};
    \node [box, below=of b2]     (b3)   {Box 3};

    % Second column
    \node [box, right=of b2]   (b4) {Box 4};

    % Labels at top
    \node [above=of b1, font=\large] (title1) {\underline{Column One}};
    \node [font=\large,text centered] at (title1-|b4) {\underline{Column Two}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If more involved calculations are needed, the `let` construct (requires the `calc` library) can be used to get the other nodes coordinates (in this case, the `y` coordinate of `(title1)` and the `x` coordinate of `(b4)`) and use those coordinates to place the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1mm and 30mm, auto,
    box/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        fill=blue!20, 
        text width=5em,
        text centered,
        rounded corners, 
        minimum height=4em
    }]  

    % First column
    \node [box]                  (b1)   {Box 1};
    \node [box, below=of b1]     (b2)   {Box 2};
    \node [box, below=of b2]     (b3)   {Box 3};

    % Second column
    \node [box, right=of b2]   (b4) {Box 4};

    % Labels at top
    \node [above=of b1, font=\large] (title1) {\underline{Column One}};
    \draw let \p1=(b4), \p2=(title1) in node [font=\large,text centered] at (\x1,\y2) {\underline{Column Two}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake: you're right; I'll add your suggestion to my answer as first option and will mention let as a second option.

Comment: Great thanks, the (title1-|b4) notation works well. Just to be sure, am I right in interpreting that if  `( <p> |- <q> ) and ( <q> -| <p> )` are the same, then the dash points towards the node you want the y-coordinate from, irrespective of the order?

Comment: @Chris you're welcome and yes.

Comment: @Chris: You can get a better understanding of the `|-` syntax if you use it in a `\draw` command: Try `\draw [red] (0,0) -| (1,1); \draw [blue] (0,0) |- (1,1);` in a `tikzpicture`.